# Using AnimateCSS in ReactJs component

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, npm-install

I installed the Animate.CSS by `npm install animate.css --save` and it saved in the `./node_modules`, locally packages.

As I read the Animate.CSS documentation in Github, it said that just only add the class name such as `fadeInDown, bouceInDown...etc` in the element that I wanted to make the animation but I do not get any idea about require a class name from locally packages.

**Question**: How can we require a class name from the Animate.CSS locally package and add it in the ReactJs Component ?

*Assume*: I have a react component as following and I want to add class name as `animated bounceIn`.

```
export class SimpleInfo extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return(
        <div>My information</div>
      )
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue.
I made a new classname, copied the style from the animate.css class, and put the new class with the added css style under a reactcsstransitiongroup.

Probably not the ideal answer to your question, but it worked for me.

Comment: Well, your method is a good way however it is not suitable for my context :))

Answer (score 0):

Not sure as I can't test it, but this should work.

```
import { bounceIn } from 'animate.css'
```

Comment: if you look at the animate.css file in the node_modules directory, you will see that it is a pure CSS file. Thus, you need to import it from your CSS file e.g. `@import "~animate.css/animate.css";` See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55143326/6854455