# Can't seem to get to animate.css

Tags: npm, animate.css, brunch

So I did

```
npm install animate.css --save
```

Which installed it successfully, I can see it in my `node_modules`
I want to be able to use animate.css in my elixir-phoenix-react project.

I am just unsure where to import/require it and what the path would even be.

I tried to `@import "animate.css";` from my `app.scss` file but that did not work

I also tried to `import "animate.css/animate.min.css";` in my app.js file that also did not work.

My question is where do I import/require animate.css so that it works? I want to use it in my react components to add some animation.

Comment: Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39853767/2990234

Comment: @Anfuca I'm not using webpack and would like to stay away from it.

Answer (score 15):

After I installed animate.css in the way below

```
npm install animate.css --save
```

I simple had to import the css file like this from my node_modules:

```
@import "~animate.css/animate.css";
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

So, you can see it in your `node_modules` folder. 
Now, you can use `@import` in your css file, or just `<link>` in your `head` but using the entire path where your `animate.css` is.

It should be something like `node_modules/animate/animate.css`

If you want to use it in production, just move the css file into your styles folder.

Comment: Is there no way to avoid moving the `animate.css` file into the `/assests/css` folder? Is there no way brunch for brunch to automate something for me?

Comment: @isignisign try ```import { bounceIn } from 'animate.css'``` Original post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43064064/5544999